I am getting an error during E-value calculation using EValue package in r
I am trying to calculate E-value for the significant variables in the multivariable Cox-regression model using EValue package but I am getting an error although I followed the provided tutorial related to that package.
The current version that I am using is 4.1.3.
I had to use this website but it is time-consuming.
Here is the used code from the tutorial
library(EValue)
# compute E-value for HR = 0.56 with CI: [0.46, 0.69]
# for a common outcome
evalue(HR(0.56, rare = FALSE), lo = 0.46, hi = 0.69)
# for a rare outcome
evalue(HR(0.56, rare = TRUE), lo = 0.46, hi = 0.69)

Error in var(x, use = "pairwise.complete.obs") : 'x' is empty

Here are details for the sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] EValue_4.1.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] sjlabelled_1.2.0    tidyselect_1.2.0    dplyr_1.1.2         fastmap_1.1.1       TH.data_1.1-2       pacman_0.5.1       
 [7] mathjaxr_1.6-0      bayestestR_0.13.1   sjstats_0.18.2      digest_0.6.31       estimability_1.4.1  lifecycle_1.0.4    
[13] survival_3.5-8      magrittr_2.0.3      compiler_4.3.3      rlang_1.1.1         tools_4.3.3         utf8_1.2.3         
[19] yaml_2.3.7          data.table_1.14.8   knitr_1.45          timereg_2.0.5       multcomp_1.4-23     abind_1.4-5        
[25] purrr_1.0.1         numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 grid_4.3.3          fansi_1.0.4         mets_1.3.4          fastDummies_1.6.3  
[31] xtable_1.8-4        colorspace_2.1-0    future_1.32.0       ggplot2_3.4.2       emmeans_1.8.8       globals_0.16.2     
[37] scales_1.2.1        MASS_7.3-60.0.1     Publish_2023.01.17  insight_0.19.1      cli_3.6.1           mvtnorm_1.1-3      
[43] rmarkdown_2.25      metafor_4.2-0       generics_0.1.3      rstudioapi_0.14     future.apply_1.10.0 performance_0.10.3 
[49] modelr_0.1.11       forestmodel_0.6.2   minqa_1.2.5         stringr_1.5.1       splines_4.3.3       metadat_1.2-0      
[55] parallel_4.3.3      MetaUtility_2.1.2   vctrs_0.6.2         boot_1.3-28.1       Matrix_1.6-5        sandwich_3.0-2     
[61] carData_3.0-5       car_3.1-2           listenv_0.9.0       tidyr_1.3.0         sjPlot_2.8.14       glue_1.6.2         
[67] parallelly_1.35.0   nloptr_2.0.3        codetools_0.2-19    stringi_1.7.12      gtable_0.3.4        ggeffects_1.2.1    
[73] lme4_1.1-33         munsell_0.5.0       tibble_3.2.1        pillar_1.9.0        htmltools_0.5.7     lava_1.7.2.1       
[79] R6_2.5.1            evaluate_0.23       lattice_0.22-5      backports_1.4.1     broom_1.0.4         Rcpp_1.0.10        
[85] coda_0.19-4         nlme_3.1-163        prodlim_2023.03.31  xfun_0.39           zoo_1.8-12          sjmisc_2.8.9       
[91] pkgconfig_2.0.3  

Further edits based on the comments
Here is my new sessioninfo():
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.3          future_1.32.0       generics_0.1.3      class_7.3-22        robustbase_0.95-1  
 [6] lattice_0.22-5      listenv_0.9.0       digest_0.6.31       magrittr_2.0.3      grid_4.3.3         
[11] Matrix_1.6-5        e1071_1.7-13        nnet_7.3-19         VIM_6.2.2           vcd_1.4-11         
[16] survival_3.5-8      laeken_0.5.2        fansi_1.0.4         scales_1.2.1        Publish_2023.01.17 
[21] codetools_0.2-19    abind_1.4-5         lava_1.7.2.1        cli_3.6.1           rlang_1.1.1        
[26] parallelly_1.35.0   future.apply_1.10.0 munsell_0.5.0       cowplot_1.1.1       splines_4.3.3      
[31] prodlim_2023.03.31  tools_4.3.3         parallel_4.3.3      dplyr_1.1.2         ggplot2_3.4.2      
[36] colorspace_2.1-0    ranger_0.15.1       boot_1.3-28.1       globals_0.16.2      vctrs_0.6.2        
[41] R6_2.5.1            zoo_1.8-12          proxy_0.4-27        lifecycle_1.0.4     car_3.1-2          
[46] MASS_7.3-60.0.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3     gtable_0.3.4        pillar_1.9.0        data.table_1.14.8  
[51] glue_1.6.2          Rcpp_1.0.10         DEoptimR_1.0-13     tibble_3.2.1        lmtest_0.9-40      
[56] tidyselect_1.2.0    rstudioapi_0.14     carData_3.0-5       compiler_4.3.3      sp_1.6-0  

Here are more details on the sessioninfo before running any code
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.3  tools_4.3.3     rstudioapi_0.14

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

The above code runs okay for me in a fresh R session.  Produces the expected output. Also version 4.1.3.

Can't reproduce this using EValue 4.1.3 in R4.3.3 on Linux. Which R version are you using? Add sessionInfo() to your question.

@jay.sf Thanks. I added sessionInfo() to my question. Appreciate.

Already tried Evalue::evalue(.)? What are last two lines if you just do evalue?

@jay.sf: Thx. Yes, I tried that. Using evalue results in the same error Error in var(x, use = "pairwise.complete.obs") : 'x' is empty. It works for RR as in the following code evalue(RR(0.80), 0.71, 0.91).

Evalue::evalue(Evalue::HR(.))? Maybe HR is masked.

@jay.sf Thx. I am still getting the same error.

You are aware that your sessionInfo() doesn't show a fresh R session? I have only 37 namespaces loaded after doing library(EValue), you have 91. In RStudio, Tools > Global Options > General,. uncheck all "Restore..." and set Save workspace to 'never'. Then restart RStudio and try again, only library(EValue); evalue(HR(0.56, rare = TRUE), lo = 0.46, hi = 0.69).

@jay.sf Thanks. I did that but I am still experiencing the same issue. Error in var(x, use = "pairwise.complete.obs") : 'x' is empty. I updated my sessioninfo() in the question. Appreciate your efforts.

Could you post another sessioninfo() right after starting RStudio, before running any code?

@jay.sf Thanks. I just added that. Appreciate your help.

@MohamedRahouma Not sure why you get 56 namespaces loaded, I only get 34. Maybe that's a start to investigate.
Try, checking for unexpected function calls, library loads, or changes to options and environment variables in these files: C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents\.Rprofile, C:\Program Files\R\R-x.y.z\etc\Rprofile.site, C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents\.Renviron, C:\Users\YourUsername\Documents\.RData. The paths may differ slightly depending on your settings. Otherwise, I'm at my wit's end, and I recommend deleting, purging and reinstalling R and RStudio with the latest versions.
